# showing full space as free spcae while installing ubuntu 14.04 !please help!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Im using Lenovo Yoga pro 2, 128GB SSD. I need to have ubuntu along side windows 8.1. My Cdrive is 98GB and made an unallocated space of 20GB to install ubuntu. while installing the partition table doesnt shows any drives(no C:/ ,, no backup) and shows 128gb as free space(that means full)!

[image]

Comment: If possible, could you upload a screenshot of the installation process at this point? Also, try the manual partitioning option and creating the partition *in* the installer, rather than before running it.

Comment: cant add snapshot, says need more reputation! can u give me ur email id? @DonaldBrown

Comment: Can you at least upload it to imgur and link to it?

Comment: Did you turn off things in Windows like dynamic partitioning, raid, fastboot, etc?  All those things will interfere with an install.

Comment: @John added!!!!

Comment: didn't it give you an option at the first screen on "install Ubuntu next to Windows" ?

Comment: No it didn't had that option @Alvar

Comment: Did you use GPT or MSDOS as the base partition table?

Comment: @john I dont think i used this! But if you can elaborate this, will help! Thanks!

Comment: A partition table is a method of organizing the partitions / filesystems on a given storage device.
On modern computers there are two primary structures for doing this, being MSDOS and GPT.
There have been a few instances in the past where the installer doesn't recognize which type is in use (either due to a bug or some 'exotic' non-standard partition scheme). If this is the case, Ubuntu cannot find any partitions, as it couldn't find the table that lists where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try gparted (it's installed on the ubuntu install disk, you can just launch it from the dash).

If gparted sees your windows partition, just create your additional partition there and apply.

If it doesn't, you will have to fix it from the windows "administrative tools" (make sure the partitions are fine there, no exotic windows specific stuff).

If you can't fix your partitions neither using gparted, nor with the windows partitioning tool, then backup your data, make sure you have a windows installation media, and repartition your disk using gparted, then install windows in a partition and linux in the other.